# Which module is required for "Get-AzureRmWebApp"?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script with cmdlet Get-AzureRmWebApp but get the error

Get-AzureRmWebApp : The term 'Get-AzureRmWebApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.

I have installed module Az and AzureRM which I thought will be the one, but no luck.
Is there any aother command after Install-Module -Name AzureRM that is required ?

thanks

Comment: while the info from `jfrmilner` solved your problem, you may want to keep the MSDocs site in mind for future reference. the page for the cmdlet you list has the module listed right at the top - `Module:    AzureRM.Websites`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Websites
```

Refrence - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/?view=azurermps-6.13.0